# Android facebook webdialog network error (netstack: lib_mgr error)

Tags: java, android, facebook, cocos2d-x

I'm connected to the internet AND I've requested internet permissions in my AndroidManifest.

Whenever I attempt to open a webdialog as follows it begins to open, then closes immediately and I get "network error". The exception is a FacebookServiceException and the httpresponsecode is -1.

Also my logcat displays:

```
02-11 17:08:57.355: E/(3491): netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
02-11 17:08:57.355: E/(3491): netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: spl_proc_plugin.so
02-11 17:08:57.355: E/(3491): netstack:  STAT_HUB - App ***** isn't supported
02-11 17:08:57.385: E/(3491): netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib libsocketpoolextend.so
```

Here is my code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
              //String s = fbMe.get(0) + " invited you to play Draw!";
            params.putString("Let's play!", "PLAY");
        WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(Draw.me,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                Toast.makeText(Draw.me.getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Draw.me.getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Network Error", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            final String requestId = values.getString("request");

                            if (requestId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(Draw.me.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        values.toString(),  
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Draw.me.getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                })
                .build();
        requestsDialog.show();
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem in my test app, I realized I had forgotten the `INTERNET` permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```